# How to show FPS without scripting when playing in Unity editor?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I did not find the `stats` tab mentioned in the book from which I am learning Unity. I googled it but it seems the `stats` has been removed several years ago.

My question: Is there any way to show FPS in Unity editor but without writing a script?

Unity Version: `2019.3.0a5 Personal`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Rendering Statistics](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RenderingStatistics.html) window still exists and shows the FPS.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I found it.

Comment: Happy to help :)